# How to switch IMAP folder in mutt?

Tags: email, mutt, imap

Hello how do I switch between IMAP folders in mutt?
I have several folders in one IMAP account:

- Inbox
- Sent
- Trash
- Old
- Spam

... etc

but all I can see is inbox.
I have tried reading the help text, and man mutt and looked on
http://mutt.org/

I must be missing something obvious
thanks

Comment: In a default configuration, you type ‘c’ to change to another folder.  Is that not working?

Comment: Ahh thanks thats the trick, then I had to hit enter to get a list of folders.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but in the context of moving a message to a different folder. In the message list I press s, then ? and see a list of mailboxes. But I cannot find a way to select a folder in the IMAP mailbox as a destination for the message.

Comment: c doesn't show all of them for me.