# Moving a message to a different IMAP folder in mutt

Tags: mutt, imap

Let's say I do

```
$ mutt -f imaps://.......%40...........:......@............com/INBOX.Spam
```

and I want to move a certain message there in INBOX.Spam to INBOX.Junk .
How do I do that?

[How to switch IMAP folder in mutt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674420/how-to-switch-imap-folder-in-mutt) is not about *moving*. Also by default with "c" one sees local folders not IMAP folders.

[mutt: save message to specific folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102829/mutt-save-message-to-specific-folder) is not about IMAP folders.